# How to stop tomcat server safely when shutdown port is -1

Tags: security, tomcat9

As per tomcat security documentation I have disabled tomcat shutdown port due to security concerns.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-howto.html#Server

Now I am unable to shutdown tomat using shutdown.bat/shutdown.sh.

Can anyone help me with script or command to stop tomcat server safey if shutdown port is disabled?

Answer (score 2):

**On linux**: catalina.sh the script try to shutdown tomcat gracefully calling

> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap stop

This try calling shutdown command on shutdown port configured server.xml

If it not succeed it will try with kill command.

**On Windows**: the start/stop is done by service and don't use the shutdown port. If you use startup.bat and shutdown.bat (not recommended in production), the shutdown will not work with shutdown port disabled (-1)